# How to use XML response in react-native

Tags: json, xml, react-native

I am developing an mobile application by `react-native`, I have to call a odata service which returns `XML` and I need to convert that to `json` object.

How should I do that?

```
return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: config.api.auth,
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      // .then(response => response.text())
      // .then(xml => _xmlToJson(xml))
      .then(json => dosomething(json))
      .catch(ex => showError(ex));
  };
```

I tried to get `text()` instead on `json()` and pass it to another method which converts `xml` to `json` but the problem is that method needs a `xml object` but `text()` returns string, and I couldn't find a way in `react-native` to convert `string` to `xml`.

p.s. Since React Native using `JavaScriptCore`, which is just a javascript interpreter, so no Browser Object Model, no document object, no window, etc can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although answer of Daniel Schmidt is correct, I used the way that is described in this article, [Build a YouTube playlist browser with React Native and Siphon](https://getsiphon.com/docs/build-a-youtube-browser/)

```
npm install xmldom
```

---

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
```

---

```
parseVideos: function(s) {
  console.log('Parsing the feed...');
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(s, 'text/xml');
  var objs = [];
  var videos = doc.getElementsByTagName('yt:videoId');
  var thumbs = doc.getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail');
  for (var i=0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    objs.push({
      id: videos[i].textContent,
      thumbnail: thumbs[i].getAttribute('url')
    })
  }
  this.setState({videos: objs});
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use any xml2js library there is in the node realm, for example https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Comment: I get this error on installing it, ` Failed at the node-expat@2.3.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'` and I couldn't solve it :(

Comment: Sorry, I picked the wrong one. I edited the answer, please have a look at this one

Comment: Yes, I found that one yesterday and it converts to json but the output json object is not good, it converts values to array, so I for getting a simple string I need to read it from array. BTW thanks

Comment: I would simply transform the resulting object, it is quite easy with javascript. Parsing xml is not.

Answer (score 1):

hope so this will helpful

first Install the dependency

```
npm i xml-js
```

[xml Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)

Run this code Snippet it will convert your Xml file to Json or Js file and destruct the data.

[expo Online Editor](https://snack.expo.dev/)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import convert from 'xml-js'; ///if this library will create issue then 
var parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

var xml =`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- CONFIGURACOES IIS -->
    <add key="ProjetoCliente" value="ESocialDev2019" />
    <add key="URLProjeto" value="http://localhost/ESocialDev2019" />
    <add key="URLLogin" value="http://localhost/ESocialDev2019/F3M" />
    <!-- /CONFIGURACOES IIS -->
    <!-- CONFIGURACOES BASEDADOS -->
    <add key="ModoSAAS" value="False" />
    <add key="NomeBDSAAS" value="F3MESocial" />
    <add key="ServidorSQL" value="DSI-SQL-01" />
    <add key="InstanciaSQL" value="F3M2014" />
    <add key="UtilizadorSQL" value="F3MES" />
    <add key="PasswordSQL" value="" />
    <add key="PasswordSQLSA" value="" />
    <add key="BDEmpresa" value="F3MES" />
    <add key="BDGeral" value="F3MESGeral" />
    <!-- /CONFIGURACOES BASEDADOS -->
  </appSettings>`;

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(()=>{


// Solution One
const json = xmltoJson(xml)
console.log("test", json)



  // Solution Two 

    parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(result));
});
  },[])
  const xmltoJson=(xml)=>{
    return convert.xml2js(xml)
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}/>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
First install [react-native-xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-xml2js) using `npm i react-native-xml2js`.

Then just parse the XML like so.

```
import {parseString} from 'react-native-xml2js';

const App = () => {
  const xml = ...;  // The XML to be parsed goes here.
  parseString(xml, (err, parsedJson) => {
    if (err === null) {
      console.log(parsedJson);
    } else {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });

  return(
    <></>
  );
};

export default App;
```